# Get the input text from Entry widget in Tkinter and use it

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have searched for a couple of hours but can't find someone with the same problem. My question comes after the code.

```
class Interface:
    def __init__(self, root):
            --- Stuff Here ---
            self.hEntry = Entry(lFrame)
            self.hEntry.bind("<Return>", self.aMethodToGetText)
            --- Stuff Here ---

    def aMethodToGetText(self, event):
            return event.widget.get()

    def anotherMethod(self):
            --- Stuff Here ---
            self.hEntry.pack()
            h = self.aMethodToGetText()??????????????????
            --- Stuff Here ---
```

I want to give my variable *h* the value that the method *aMethodToGetText* returns. Calling it like that will ofc give an error:

TypeError: aMethodToGetText() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

Using h = self.aMethodToGetText(self.hEntry) and removing *widget.* doesn't work either.

It can be solved easy if you have 1 Entry. But I have many Entrys and have to make a general text getter method for all my Entrys.

**EDIT:** So I need one function for each entry? I want to use each entry in different conditions, functions and slicing. That's why I need a variable for each entry. I can't move my code in anotherMethod(self) to aMethodToGetText(self, event) because I don't want the function to start over every time the Enter-button is pressed. If I press Enter on any entry I want them to do the same thing, assign the entry to a variable. But each entry should be assigned to a different variable. I need to compare the entrys with each other.

**EDIT 2:**

```
class Interface:
    def __init__(self, root):
            --- Stuff Here ---
            self.aListForEntries = []
            self.hEntry = Entry(lFrame)
            self.hEntry.bind("<Return>", self.aMethodToGetText)
            self.aEntry = Entry(lFrame)
            self.aEntry.bind("<Return>", self.aMethodToGetText)
            --- Stuff Here ---

    def aMethodToGetText(self, event):
            entry = event.widget.get()
            self.aListForEntries.append(entry)

    def anotherMethod(self):
            --- Stuff Here ---
            self.hEntry.pack()
            h = self.entryList[0] #IndexError: list index out of range
            --- Check the first Entry ---
            self.aEntry.pack()
            a = self.entryList[1]
            --- Check the second Entry ---
            if h == a:
                Do stuff
            --- Stuff Here ---
```

I get an error because the list is empty before the user has pressed Enter. I tried to paus the script with `time.sleep(x)` before the line `h = self.entryList[0]` but that doesn't work. I don't want the program to run through the whole `anotherMethod(self)` before the user has pressed Enter.

Comment: @noscreenname the first parameter `self` is implied as it is a method- it would need one parameter, `event`.

Comment: If you have multiple entries then could you provide an example of such a case. The solution would differ greatly depending on what you want to do for each entry. If you press enter on any entry, should they all do the same thing or each something different? If different then you can't have a general function unless you add conditions of what to do if this or that entry is used.

Comment: @StevenSummers So I need one function for each entry? I want to use each entry in different conditions, functions and slicing. That's why I need a variable for each entry. I can't move my code in anotherMethod(self) to aMethodToGetText(self, event) because I don't want the function to start over every time the <Return>-button is pressed.

EDIT: If I press enter on any entry I want them to do the same thing, assign the entry to a variable. But each entry should be assigned to a different variable. I need to compare the entrys with each other.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Example has two entry widgets that configures the label to displays if the contents match.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self._master = master

        self._lbl = tk.Label(master, text = '?')
        self._lbl.pack(side = tk.LEFT)

        self.hEntry = tk.Entry(master)
        self.hEntry.bind("<Return>", self.update)
        self.hEntry.pack()

        self.aEntry = tk.Entry(master)
        self.aEntry.bind("<Return>", self.update)
        self.aEntry.pack()

    def update(self, event):
        if self.hEntry.get() == self.aEntry.get():
            self._lbl.config(text = "Match")
        else:
            self._lbl.config(text = "No Match")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Not really what I want. Let say I have 2 Entrys and I want to compare the inputs that the user writes with an if-statement. How do I do that?  See my EDIT 2.

Comment: I have edited my answer, Is this what you were after?

Comment: I want to display one entry at the time. I want to check if the first input is correct before showing the second entry. I have updated my post.

My code is 300 lines. I don't want to show my code here, sorry.

Answer (score -2):

don't know if would work, but have you tried with lambda? something like:

```
lambda event, h = event.widget.get(): self.aMethodToGetText(event)
```